# Decompress Data Stream Component: Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted

Tags: c#, xml, stream, deserialization

I am trying to decompress/deserialize a datastream that is saved within an XML file attribute. The data was compressed with Delphi's `Stream.WriteComponent()` method. It ultimately throws this error:

**exception:** 
*System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted.*

**First I retrieve the datastream using a XML LINQ Query:**

```
var dataStream = 
(
    from XmlNode xn in nList
    where xn?.Attributes != null 
    && xn?.Attributes["Name"].InnerText == "Columns"
    select xn.Attributes["StreamData"].InnerText
).ToList()[0x0];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataStream) { return; }
```

**I then proceed to take the XML attributes InnerText and turn it into stream data:**

```
var byteStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataStream);
var memStream = new MemoryStream
(
    byteStream,
    0,
    byteStream.Length,
    true,
    true
);
```

**I then proceed to try and decompress the datastream:**

```
var rslt = Decompress(stream);
```

**And this is what the Decompress() function looks like:**

```
public static string Decompress(MemoryStream stream)
{
    using (var uncompressed = new MemoryStream())
    using (var compressed = stream)
    using (var ds = new DeflatedStream(compressed, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        ds.CopyTo(uncompressed);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uncompressed.ToArray());
    }
}
```

**The XML file looks similar to this but not identical(it is valid xml i promise):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item Class="Item" Name="Default" GUID="{BC0EE2E4-641F-44DA-A989-F97C58B1828D}">
  <Properties>
    <Property Class="Type" GUID="{3A6C51FB-BE2E-4DBF-B2C5-8EB7C3508529}" Name="Type" group="Item" OrderIndex="0" DecimalPlaces="2">blah</Property>
    <Property Class="Text" GUID="{1119FF79-74C6-42AF-918F-1AF485614D07}" Name="Name" inheritaction="Ignore" required="True" group="Item" OrderIndex="1" DecimalPlaces="2">blahblah</Property>
    <Property Class="Number" GUID="{AF1BC5FD-A4DD-4610-92EE-2F7D7EA4FA64}" Name="OrderIndex" systemhidden="True" OrderIndex="3" DecimalPlaces="2">0</Property>
    <Property Class="Text" GUID="{176382CA-7E00-47C2-8DD3-82A9ED4FB973}" Name="GUID" inheritaction="Ignore" systemlocked="True" systemhidden="True" OrderIndex="4" DecimalPlaces="2">{BC0EE2E4-641F-44DA-A989-F97C58B1828D}</Property>
    <Property Class="Stream" GUID="{833CB9FD-4914-4899-B757-CC9C130E6914}" Name="Columns" OrderIndex="5" DecimalPlaces="2" StreamData="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"/>

  </Properties>
</Item>
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that created the file, or a sample file, we have to guess what you've actually done

Comment: I updated it with the xml

Comment: I have a feeling that it will come down to an issue with incompatible zlib headers. Decode the base64 and inspect the headers. Getting the Delphi code would help!

Comment: I don't have access to the Delphi code unfortunately

Comment: I did add a nuget for zlib .net but hadn't used it, and I'm a bit confused by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XML is a string and decompression almost certainly expects binary data as the input, then the value of the `StreamData` attribute must be an ASCII/string encoded representation of binary data.  This could be using a simple bin-2-hex notation but from the example provided in the question, it looks more likely to be **base64** or similar.

Whoever is providing the XML should be able to confirm the encoding for you.

In any event, we can be fairly certain that the `StreamData` has to be in a string encoded form since otherwise the binary data will contain values that will result in an invalid XML file (e.g. bytes with value 0 etc)

That being the case then your problem is that `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` interprets the data it is passed simply as an array of bytes.  That is, it expects that the bytes it is given are part of a valid UTF8 encoded string.  It does *not* do any conversion from hexadecimal characters to binary bytes etc.

That is, to use a very simplistic example, if your `StreamData` is a string with the value `"000102"` then your code will currently yield a `byteStream` that has content consisting of 6 (six) bytes with values as follows:

```
StreamData :  '0' '0' '0' '1' '0' '2'
bytes      : [30][30][30][31][30][32]    (hexadecimal byte values)
```

When what you probably are expecting is a stream of 3 (three) bytes with values corresponding to the `StreamData` as follows:

```
StreamData : '00''01''02'
bytes      : [00][01][02]                (hexadecimal byte values)
```

i.e. you will need to properly decode the `StreamData` string to it's in-memory, binary representation before passing it to the **Decompress()** routine which is complaining currently because the binary data it is being supplied is not  valid, compressed data.

You need to confirm the encoding of the binary data in `StreamData` and apply the appropriate decoding to obtain the binary representation of that data before passing this to the **Decompress()** routine, rather than the raw/original string representation.

Comment: The only thing I do know for certain is that whoever compressed it used Stream.WriteComponent via Delphi/Pascal. Thank you-I will try what you have recommended.

Comment: Here is a fairly large chunk of the streamdata attribute: StreamData="Bhl0bEVzdGltYXRpbmcudGxFc3RpbWF0aW5nBgtUY3hUcmVlTGlzdAIAAgoGBUJhbmRzBhBUY3hUcmVlTGlzdEJhbmRzAgACAQYFQmFuZDAGD1RjeFRyZWVMaXN0QmFuZAIFBgdDYXB0aW9uAggGAAYMUmVhbE1pbldpZHRoAgYCFAYJUmVhbFdpZHRoAgYCAAYHVmlzaWJsZQIIBgRUcnVlBgVJbmRleAIGAgACAAYGQ29sdW1uBh1UcHNjeEVzdGltYXRpbmdUcmVlTGlzdENvbHVtbgILBgdWaXNpYmxlAggGBFRydWUGBUluZGV4AgYCAAYJTGluZUNvdW50AgYCAQYIQ29sSW5kZXgCBgIABghSb3dJbmRleAIGAgAGCUJhbm

Comment: I put the stream data attribute in my example if that helps

Comment: Sure looks like **base64** to me.  Whoever is providing the XML file should be able to confirm for you.  :)

Comment: Hey so I finally got it to work similar to how you recommended but now I don't know what to do with what it is returning: "TPF0TpscxEstimatingTreeListColumnColumnCaption.TextNameDataBinding.ValueTypeStringWidth8Position.ColIndex" its just a garbled string ...

Comment: The `TPF0` at the start indicates this is a Delphi component stream.  The **Tpscx...** is the name of the class of the "root" object stored in the stream.  This will be something in your application which you will need to restore from the stream using the "ReadComponent()" mechanism provided for such things.  At this point I think you need to consult some references on Delphi object streaming (there are plenty online).

Comment: Will do. One thing I'm curious is the ReadComponent method you speak of. Which class is that associated with?

Comment: The problem is how to write that code from C#. It sounds like I will need to create and adapter or a wrapper.

Comment: Trying to "load" a streamed Delphi component in a C# application is an entirely different problem.  Sounds like you need a new question (but there is almost certainly no general answer to that question:  the solution is going to be very application specific since it involves applications specific classes.  i.e. those in the stream).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106513/discussion-between-anthony-guertin-and-deltics).